# Avoiding infinite loop because of API response in interceptor

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, http-status-code-401, angular-http-interceptors

I am developing Angular 6 application and there is one usecase in which I am stuck. I have following interceptor code

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const authReq = req.clone({
      withCredentials : true
    });

    if (!window.navigator.onLine) {
      // if there is no internet, throw a HttpErrorResponse error
      // since an error is thrown, the function will terminate here
      const error = {
        status: 0,
        error: {
          description: 'Check Connectivity!'
        },
        statusText: 'Check Connectivity!'
      };
      return throwError(new HttpErrorResponse(error));
    } else {
      // else check if error is 401, if yes then logout
      return next.handle(authReq)
          .pipe(
          timeout(60000),
          tap(
            event => {

                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    let header: HttpHeaders = event.headers;
                    console.log(header.get('Set-Cookie'))
                }
            },
            error => {
              if (error.name && error.name === 'TimeoutError') {
                this.toastrService.error('API took too long to respond', 'Error', { closeButton: true, disableTimeOut: true });
              } else if (error.status === 401) {
                this.toastrService.error("Unauthenticated, Logging Out!")
                this.logoutUser()
              }
              else if((error.status ==403))
                  this.toastrService.error("You are Unauthorized to access the resource")
              else
                this.toastrService.error("Unknown Error Occurred")
            }
          )
        );
    }
  }
```

The logoutUser() function which is executed if there is 401 response initiates a logout flow. The function call another to logout the user and it may also return 401 response. This will create a infinite loop. How to avoid this situation?

Comment: Since the server already response 401, probably the used is already logged out, so you just can redirect to the login, other approach is that the logout method be public, if is public it won't return 401

Comment: I have to mandatorily call the logout server api on 401. Also I can change the api to public as I have don't have control over it.

Comment: You can make your logout method in the server side public as the login.

Comment: I can't change the server side code @DiegoBascans